# Keep Floating Actionbutton above Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button, android-snackbar

How can I keep the FloatingActionbutton above the "blue bottom bar" when scrolling down? The bar is the last element of my Fragment so it only needs to move up by a few dp.

Behaviour should be similar to the Snackbar behaviour.

[image: Example Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the BottomBar's ViewHolder is different from the other items in your Recycler view's adapter. You can create an interface that communicates with your FAB whenever the BottomBar's viewholder is bidden in the onBindViewHolder method. If it is, it fires off and some other method checks whether the lastvisible position is equal to the BottomBar's position 
For example.

**Your Adapter**

```
    public class SomeAdapter extends extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SomeAdapter.ViewHolder>{

OnBottomBarBinned onBottomBarBinned;

public interface OnBottomBarBinned{
void binned();
  }

 public SomeAdapter(OnBottomBarBinned onBottomBarBinned){
  this.onBootmBarBinned = onBottomVarBinned;
 }

public static class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

 ViewHolder(View v){
   super(v);
 }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder,int position){
      if(viewHolder.item.getViewId()==R.id.yourBottomBarId){
        onBottomBarBinned.binned();
   }}

} 


}
```

Then when attaching the adapter

```
 yourRecyclerView.setAdapter(new SomeAdapter(new OnBottomBarBinned(){
      void binned(){
    if(yourLayoutManager.findLastVisiblePosition==bottomBarPosition){
  yourFab.setTranslationY(someDp);
 }
   else{
   yourFab.setTranslationY(0);
 }

  }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a FrameLayout/ CoordinatorLayout? This should be easily accomplished if you keep your FAB declared above your bottom bar in XML.